# Finding mixed data type from multiple columns at one shot

Tags: python-3.x

I have dataframe with 2 million rows and 15 columns. I need to find out if any columns have mixed data type data.
I tried for one column using below code to see if that column has anything other than int, it does give me a list with 2 million rows and their data type. But I need to run a code in such a way that with single code, it checks all columns for mixed data type and gives the name of the column/s in the output that has mixed data type. Can you please help?

[df_orders['order_id'].map(type) != int]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The data I have has different columns.
user_id, order_number,product_id,...etc
And each column has data in either int64 or str format.

I want to make sure that there is no mixed type data in any columns. For example, in order_number column, all rows has data in int64 format. If any row has data not in int64 format, then I need to know.